# Handler Smart Card Reader

Tags: c, linux, pcsc, reader

I'm writting app connect to Smart Card reader,
And I want to connect 2 app to 2 Reader:

```
# Detected readers (pcsc)
Nr.  Card  Features  Name
0    Yes             ACS ACR38U 00 00
1    Yes             ACS ACR38U-CCID 01 00
```

But, App only connects to Reader 0: ACS ACR38U 00 00.
I try with IFDHandler but it is not ok.
Please help me with connecting 2 apps to 2 readers 0 and 1.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "I try with IFDHandler but not ok"

Comment: I use function IFDHCreateChannel() in lib ifdhandler.h but undifined, 
And use IFDHandler to handle this problem is true ???
I don't know how, please help me if you can @dotcomly

Comment: I can not help you because I have no experience with this, I just know a bad question when I see one. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and ask your question again.

Comment: I know this because my English not good and I begin use stackoverflow not long time,
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your English is not the problem, the problem is you did not explain your problem in detail. Give as many details as you can, even if it is not perfect English.

Answer (score 0):

(If I understand well)

You *probably* need to change the second argument of the function `SCardConnect()` to get a different reader.

I.e. put `"ACS ACR38U-CCID 01 00"` here to get the second reader.

Good luck!

Comment: I handled problem. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: @DuongHa I am glad to hear that. It would be nice if you shared your solution (you can post an answer to you own question). And doing the same with the [second post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384708/how-to-connect-two-smart-card-reader-simultaneous-with-2-application) would be really appreciated. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I use opensc-tool -l:

```
# Detected readers (pcsc)
Nr.  Card  Features  Name
0    Yes             ACS ACR38U 00 00
1    Yes             ACS ACR38U-CCID 01 00
```

Then I get Name Reader 0 ( ACS ACR38U 00 00) for func **SConnect()** in App 1.
Name Reader 1 ( ACS ACR38U-CCID 01 00) for func ***SConnect()*** in App 2.
The present, I only can handle so. 
If have you other handle maybe share for me?