# How to Connect two Smart Card Reader simultaneous with 2 Application

Tags: c, linux, reader

I'm writting app use function [SCardConnect()](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/group__API.html#ga4e515829752e0a8dbc4d630696a8d6a5) in lib winscard.h
If run 2 app it only can Connect to one Reader 0 (Ex have 2 Reader 0 and Reader 1)
How do connect to 2 Readers simultaneous?

Comment: Is this the same issue as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382659/handler-smart-card-reader)?

Comment: If you are connecting to two _different_ readers, there should be no problem...

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I did something similar (lib with no instance handle), the solution was:
Spawn a process for each reader. Use IPC to sync (shared memory, TCP/UDP loopback, pipes...)